# Zlib inflate and deflate errors

Tags: c++, zlib, compression

Hi everyone I am basically trying to use the zlib library, but I am having troubles when  I try to inflate a self-deflated file , although when I inflate other zlib´d files it works fine.

The compressing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned int  UINT; 
#include "zlib.h"
#define HEADERSIZE (1024)
#define CHUNKSIZE 4096
#define SWAPINT(x) (((x)&0xFF) << 24)|(((x)&0xFF00) << 8) | (((x)&0xFF0000) >> 8) | (((x)&0xFF000000) >> 24)
#define DEFLATESIZE 65536
const char *mz_error(int err)
{
  static struct { int m_err; const char *m_pDesc; } s_error_descs[] =
  {
    { Z_OK, "" }, { Z_STREAM_END, "stream end" }, { Z_NEED_DICT, "need dictionary" }, { Z_ERRNO, "file error" }, { Z_STREAM_ERROR, "stream error" },
    { Z_DATA_ERROR, "data error" }, { Z_MEM_ERROR, "out of memory" }, { Z_BUF_ERROR, "buf error" }, { Z_VERSION_ERROR, "version error" }
  };
  UINT i; for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s_error_descs) / sizeof(s_error_descs[0]); ++i) if (s_error_descs[i].m_err == err) return s_error_descs[i].m_pDesc;
  return NULL;
}

char* myinflate(char* buffer, int bufsize, int* inflatedSize)
{
    BYTE tmpinf[DEFLATESIZE];
    char* inflated=(char*)malloc(DEFLATESIZE);
    int ret,have;
    z_stream strm;
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = bufsize;
    strm.next_in = (Bytef*)buffer;
    strm.avail_out = sizeof(tmpinf);
    strm.next_out = tmpinf;
    ret = inflateInit(&strm);
    printf("%s",mz_error(ret));
    ret = inflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
    printf("%s",mz_error(ret));
    if(ret == Z_DATA_ERROR)
        printf(strm.msg);
    inflateEnd(&strm);
    have = strm.total_out;
    printf("%d\n",have);
    memcpy(inflated,tmpinf,have);
    *inflatedSize = have;
    return inflated;
}
char* mydeflate(char* buffer, int bufsize, int* deflatedSize)
{
    BYTE tmpdef[CHUNKSIZE*4];
    char* deflated=(char*)malloc(DEFLATESIZE);
    int have,ret;
    z_stream strm;
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = bufsize;
    strm.next_in = (Bytef*)buffer;
    strm.avail_out = sizeof(tmpdef);
    strm.next_out = tmpdef;
    ret = deflateInit(&strm,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    printf("%s",mz_error(ret));
    ret = deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
    printf("%s",mz_error(ret));
    ret = deflateEnd(&strm);
    printf("%s",mz_error(ret));
    have = strm.total_out;
    printf("%d\n",have);
    memcpy(deflated,tmpdef,have);
    *deflatedSize = have;
    return deflated;
}
int main()
{
    FILE* fptr = fopen("test.in","rb");
    fseek (fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size  = ftell(fptr);
    fseek (fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(size);
    fread(buffer,1,size,fptr);
    int infsize,defsize;
    char* buf = myinflate(buffer,size,&infsize);
    FILE* out = fopen("testinf.hex","wb");
    fwrite(buf,1,infsize,out);
    fclose(out);
    char* buf2 = mydeflate(buf,infsize,&defsize);
    out  = fopen("testdef.hex","wb");
    fwrite(buf2,1,defsize,out);
    fclose(out);
    int buf3size;
    char* buf3 = myinflate(buf2,defsize,&buf3size);
    out  = fopen("testinfdef.hex","wb");
    fwrite(buf3,1,buf3size,out);
}
```

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/364574/eEyzAbMuCp93MmGk/test.in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not checking *any* return codes.  How could you possibly expect to know what's going on?  *Check the return codes from all functions that can return errors!*

There may simply not be enough space provided for compression and/or decompression.  The return codes from `inflate()` and `compress()` indicate whether that is the case or not.

By the way, you `malloc()` `inflated` twice, overwriting the first one resulting in a massive memory leak.

Also you blithely convert an int pointer to an unsigned long pointer.  If they have different lengths, then you will have a problem.

Comment: The malloc() was a horrible copy-paste error,thank you for noticing and it´s already edited. But the long pointer is the same as the int one in my compiler and OS, and I´m not planning to port it by now. Anyways it says it´s a data error in the last inflate(), and I don´t have an idea about why does that happens.

Comment: Now that removed one of the `malloc()`'s, the existence of `tmpinf` makes no sense.  You could decompress directly into `inflated`.  Same thing for `tmpdef`.

Comment: You changed it all to print the return codes.  However you did not change your output to show what the return codes are.  What is `mz_error()`?  Also if the return code is `Z_DATA_ERROR`, you should also print `strm.msg`.

Comment: apparently the deflate() function in´t genereting generating a header, or an invalid one (incorrect header check)

Comment: typedef unsigned char BYTE, it is a standard windows datatype and practically a primitive C++ one, so I don't think that's the problem. I think it has to do with the version or compilation of the library, so the next thing I'm going to try is to download another compilation or add manually a header and an ADLER-32 trailer.Anyways thank you for all your help with your own library, Mark.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem.  However you have provided only partial source, so the problem may lie in the code you elected to not provide.

Comment: ok, I`ve edited the code and added some details to provide additional information about the system configuration.

Comment: The provided test.in file is not compressed, and so fails the provided code immediately.  I compressed it, and the code still works, not exhibiting the problem you observed.  I cannot duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had to define ZLIB_WINAPI to get the things to work with http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/zlib125dll.zip. Now it works